# TypeScript function to return nullable Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I'm trying to create a function that returns a Promise with values that can be resolved to null.

Basically something like this:

```ts
static getUserById(ids: String): Promise<?User> {
  // do something
}
```

but it is returning an error

> Generic type 'Promise' requires 1 type argument(s)

How to create a function in TypeScript that can return a Promise with nullable resolved values?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`?` means `optionnal parameter` not `nullable type`.

You should use this:

```
Promise<User|null>
```

Comment: ok... saw this link where Promise<?User> is used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etax3aEe2dA&t=1209s .. wonder how it's done

Comment: @Stanley it is flow on video, not typescript.

Comment: `strictNullChecks` should be true in `ts.config`

Comment: Thanks @sunsets, the strictNullChecks=false was removing the null and undefined types from return type of my function like `Promise<Account | undefined>` was seen from other files like `Promise<Account>`.

In the end, always set strictNullChecks=true.